# Why is the trailing of my UISwitch sticking out the UIStackView?

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview, uiswitch

I don't know if this is a Swift bug or if I made a mistake, but there is a weird behaviour.

I have a UILabel and a UISwitch inside a horizontal UIStackView, but the trailing of the UISwitch is cut off because it's sticking out the stackView (see images).

[App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfBOW.png)

[UI debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lybr.png)

Does anyone have a similar problem or is it just me?
And if it's a Swift bug, is there a workaround?

Here is my code:

```swift
private lazy var alreadyInPlaceStackView: UIStackView = {
    UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [alreadyInPlaceLabel, alreadyInPlaceSwitch],
                axis: .horizontal,
                spacing: Constants.horizontalPadding,
                alignment: .fill,
                distribution: .fill)
}()

private lazy var alreadyInPlaceLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.conference.background.on_background
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.font = UIFont.label
    label.text = "report.intubation.already-in-place.title".localized()

    return label
}()

private lazy var alreadyInPlaceSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let view = UISwitch()
    view.onTintColor = UIColor.conference.highlight.primary
    view.addTarget(self,
                   action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)),
                   for: .valueChanged)
    view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    return view
}()
```

Constraints:

```swift
alreadyInPlaceStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: switchStackViewContainerView.leadingAnchor),
alreadyInPlaceStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: switchStackViewContainerView.trailingAnchor),
alreadyInPlaceStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoLaryngoscopeStackView.bottomAnchor, constant: Constants.verticalPadding),
alreadyInPlaceStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: switchStackViewContainerView.bottomAnchor),

switchStackViewContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailsContainer.leadingAnchor),
switchStackViewContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
switchStackViewContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: difficultIntubationStackView.bottomAnchor, constant: Constants.verticalPadding),
switchStackViewContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailsContainer.bottomAnchor),
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the trailing constraint of alreadyInPlaceStackView with its superView?

Comment: I've added the constraints I have for the stackView to the description. And in the View debugger I can clearly see that it's sticking out^^

Comment: Here is a basic sample project. You can clearly see that the switch is not entirely inside the stackView: [GitHub Project](https://github.com/fabi-an-ro/StackViewLayoutTestProject)

Comment: @FabianR. - interesting bug -- definitely worth reporting to Apple. Setting the **trailing** anchor of a `UISwitch` (or when embedded in a stack view as you have shown) offsets the trailing edge by 2-points.

Comment: Ok thanks! I've reported it to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to do a little more investigation on this... I was wrong about the "trailing" aspect.

Let's look at a simple example -- we'll add a blue `UIView` and a `UISwitch`, and constrain the width of the blue view to the width of the switch:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let theSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let v = UISwitch()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()
    
    let blueView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [blueView, theSwitch].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        view.addSubview(theSwitch)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // blueView width and height equal to theSwitch
            blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.widthAnchor),
            blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.heightAnchor),
            
            // blueView top and leading
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // theSwitch top to blueView bottom, leading to blueView leading
            theSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("blueView  width:", blueView.frame.width)
        print("theSwitch width:", theSwitch.frame.width)
    }
    
}
```

Here's what we get:

[image]

and, if we tap, we see this in the Debug Console:

```
blueView  width: 49.0
theSwitch width: 51.0
```

The switch is 2-points wider than the blue view!!!

---

So, let's try setting the blue view's width constraint *after* the switch has been fully laid-out.

We comment-out the width constraint:

```
        // don't set blueView width
        //blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.widthAnchor),
        // blueView height equal to theSwitch
        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.heightAnchor),
```

and on tap, we'll set it:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // now we set blueView width
    blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    // print widths after layout pass
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("blueView  width:", self.blueView.frame.width)
        print("theSwitch width:", self.theSwitch.frame.width)
    }

}
```

Looks like this before tap (because blueView has no width):

[image]

and after tap:

[image]

and console output is again:

```
blueView  width: 49.0
theSwitch width: 51.0
```

Equal is apparently not always Equal !!!

---

Let's look at a common use-case -- we will embed a label and a switch in a view (or, as in your example, a stack view) for "Option" toggles:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let theSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let v = UISwitch()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()
    
    let blueView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return v
    }()
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Option 1:"
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [blueView, theSwitch, theLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // let's embed theSwitch and theLabel in blueView
        blueView.addSubview(theLabel)
        blueView.addSubview(theSwitch)
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // we're going to right-align the switch in the blue view
            blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128.0),
            
            // blueView height equal to theSwitch + 16 (so we have 8-points top/bottom "padding"
            blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.heightAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            
            // blueView top and leading
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // center theLabel vertically and left-align it
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerYAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // center theSwitch vertically
            theSwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerYAnchor),
            
            // right-align theSwitch
            theSwitch.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // clear the background colors
        blueView.backgroundColor = .clear
        theSwitch.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        // set clipsToBounds
        blueView.clipsToBounds = true
        
    }
    
}
```

and we get this:

[image]

On tap we'll clear the backgrounds, AND we'll turn on `clipsToBounds` for the blue view:

[image]

---

<s>This is what I would call, clearly, a ***bug***.</s>

Worth noting... if we evaluate the `intrinsicContentSize` of the switch:

```
print("theSwitch.intrinsicContentSize:", theSwitch.intrinsicContentSize)
print("theSwitch.frame.size          :", theSwitch.frame.size)
```

Console shows:

```
theSwitch.intrinsicContentSize: (49.0, 31.0)
theSwitch.frame.size          : (51.0, 31.0)
```

---

**Edit**

Based on Matt's answer and explanation of the `alignmentRectInsets` of `UISwitch`, I'll retract my claim of this being a "bug" and instead accept that it is *intended layout behavior*.

I'll leave my example code and images here though (as an exercise in futility).

Comment: It's not a bug. This is very misleading. It is simply the alignment rect insets doing exactly what they are intended to do. You may not _like_ it but that doesn't make anything about this a bug.

Comment: @matt - hmmm? A UIControl with an intrinsic content size that is **not** its actual size... `.widthAnchor` equal to `.widthAnchor` that does **not** result in equal widths... a `UIControl` that frames itself **not** based on the given constraints... Neither documented nor consistent with defined auto-layout behavior, but *"exactly what they are intended to do"*?

Comment: As I've explained in my answer, this is simply the alignment rect insets doing exactly what they are intended to do. If you don't like it, you don't like it, but that doesn't make it a bug.

Comment: @matt - acknowledged... and I added an **Edit** to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. This entire affair is based on a misunderstanding of the layout of a UISwitch. Run the app and output the UISwitch's `alignmentRectInsets`. You will see:

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 2.0)
```

The effect you are seeing is exactly what the `alignmentRectInsets` is intended to do; it changes the point at which constraints are pinned to the view. Here, the right / trailing anchor is pinned to a point two points inset from the visible edge of the UISwitch.

This is a common technique when the physical size of a view does not correspond to the way the view is drawn. Here, I presume that the right-side curve is considered by Apple to be slightly outside the "true" body of the UISwitch.

You can complain to Apple if you want, but I doubt you'll get any satisfaction. Clearly Apple *wants* things to line up with the right end of a UISwitch in this way. If you don't like the way this works, you can simply compensate, knowing about the inset. Alternatively, you can make your own UISwitch subclass that changes the inset:

```
class MySwitch: UISwitch {
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets { .zero }
}
```

Comment: But when I add a UISwitch to a UIStackView, I would presume that the whole UISwitch is inside the stackView?!

Comment: That's the trouble with stack views. They work by creating constraints. In this case the stack view generates a trailing constraint, which, as I have just explained to you, pins the trailing edge of the stack view to the right alignment inset of the switch.

Comment: *"That's the trouble with stack views. They work by creating constraints."* C'mon, @matt ... it has nothing to do with stack views. The issue here is that Apple has decided (without documenting it) that the trailing edge - but *not the leading edge* - of a `UISwitch` should have an inset of 2-points. Unless a dev is using SwiftUI, we are almost certainly using constraints. If we add a switch as a subview of a view with `.clipsToBounds = true`, and constrain it trailing, we have to (somehow) **know** that it will be be clipped and we have to give it extra padding.

Comment: So, yeah, I begrudgingly agree it is not a "bug" -- but let's be realistic about the fact that, in some cases, what Apple has decided is "by design" could reasonably be considered a "mistake" - or at least a bad decision.